# Git tags disappear when doing a push then clone?

Tags: git, tags

We have a repository with multiple tags. Each tag represents a version of the software. We are pushing the repository to a remote server.

When we do a fresh clone off the remote server, the tags are no longer there. How do you ensure other developers or clients can check out specific versions of software off the remote server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`git push --tags` or `git push remote tag-name`

Comment: It strikes me as odd that tags should be kept separate, i wonder why!

Comment: Actually, tags are not kept separate. The default semantics of `git push` are to push refs (branches and tags) on your local machine that have matching refs on the remote. Since any given tag doesn't yet exist on the remote, it wouldn't be pushed (and as tags are intended to be immutable, it wouldn't really make sense to update the tags anyhow). So, you need to explicitly push tags when you want them to appear on the remote.

Comment: It might need to be, I think, `git push <remote> tag <tag-name>`, i.e. the repository parameter has to be specified explicitely (because interpretation depends on position).

Comment: I don't think you have to explicitly write "tag", according to manpage it's just `git push <remote> <tag-name>` (or `git push <remote> tags/<tag-name>` to prevent conflict with other similarly-named refs.

Comment: You're right. I basically always use `git push --tags`, so I screwed up the syntax for an individual tag when checking the man page. I figured the reason for the `tag <tag-name>` syntax was to distinguish from a remote, but I guess it's basically useless (as `tag/<tag-name>` works just as well).

Answer (score 9):

Alternate solution to the one [given by Brian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628652/git-tags-dissapear-when-doing-a-push-then-clone/1628662#1628662) would be to configure remote to push all refs, or push all branches and tags:

```
[remote "repository"]
        url = user@example.com:user/repo.git
        push  = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
        push  = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that, since [git 1.8.3 (April 22d, 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L131-L132), a:

```
git push --follow-tags
```

would push any new commits as well as all annotated tags referenced by pushed commits.